# "Service Temporarily Unavailable" after installing module on Magento site

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed a plugin, after that my site is showing the below message:

**"Service Temporarily Unavailable"**

Please help. My site is www.arrgosy.com

Comment: show us server log, magento log

Comment: I haven't disable it. Can you please tell me its location?

Comment: <magento_root_folder> var/log/system.log and exception.log . For apache log read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/where-are-apache-file-access-logs-stored (if you are using apache)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Magento has a built in procedure for safety when installing a new module, and at the same time try to access the store. It adds a file **maintenance.flag** at the root.

This avoids runtime errors for users.

Remove the **maintenance.flag** flag to return to normal.