# How to solve the Service Temporarily Unavailable?

Tags: admin, maintenance

My website is showing:

> Service Temporarily Unavailable - The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

I cannot access the site or the admin back end.
I can see some similar questions regarding this issue and I have tried all the various answers. Whilst they work for a couple of hours, the issue returns.

So I have deleted the maintenance file. I have deleted the session files. I have deleted the cache folders both on the admin panel in Magento and through Filezilla and as I delete some, they return in front of my eyes! The site comes back and I get access to admin, but 2 or so hours later and the problem is back.

**Can anyone please help to finally get rid of this issue once and for all?**

Comment: What's your Magento version?

Comment: Please check this link [Click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65661/service-temporarily-unavailable-after-installing-module-on-magento-site)

Comment: have you checked whether your magento is on maintenance mode?

Answer (score 0):

Check logs under webroot/var/log/system.log and webroot/var/log/exception.log . Check if these files have errors. After that do google research about errors you see, or do questions for specific things. Thanks.